# Is there a rhetorical term for remarks like "you're exactly what I've come to expect from..."?

Tags: figures-of-speech, rhetorical-devices

Is there a specific term for a statement that uses words such that their precise meaning conveys a subtext contrary to the colloquial meaning?

For example, the joke in *Men in Black*:

> Gentlemen, congratulations. You're everything we've come to expect
>   from years of government training.

where the precise use of the words conveys a sarcastic meaning (*ie* that the candidates are inept because that's what he's come to expect from government training).

I was going to use "irony" to describe this but then realized this is basically the opposite of irony - the use of words *to* convey their literal intention, when a nonliteral intention was expected.

Comment: is sarcasm not the right word?

Comment: @gstats I'm hoping there is something more specific.

Answer (score 3):

These are known as *backhanded compliments* or *left-handed compliments*
or *asteisms*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insult#Backhanded_compliment):

> Backhanding is slap using the back of the hand as opposed to the palm. A *backhanded compliment*, also known as a *left-handed compliment* or *asteism*, is an insult that is disguised as a compliment. Sometimes, a backhanded compliment may be inadvertent. However, the term usually connotes an intent to belittle or condescend.

And from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asteism):

> ***asteism***: Polite irony; a genteel and ingenious manner of deriding another.